# Display child categories in WooCommerce

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails, woocommerce-offtopic

This code displays the category thumbnail and title of the two parent categories for WooCommerce product categories.

I have several child categories I'd like to display as well. Is there way way to show all categories OR select which category IDs to display?

```
$taxonomyName = "product_cat";
$prod_categories = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => -1
) );  
foreach( $prod_categories as $prod_cat ) :
    if ( $prod_cat->parent != 0 )
        continue;
    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
    $term_link = get_term_link( $prod_cat, 'product_cat' );
    ?><img  src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="" /> 
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"> <?php echo $prod_cat->name; ?> </a>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution for your Question:  Please check this one, I hope it will help you to display child category details.

```
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $title        = '';
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; ?>

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                 echo  $sub_category->name ;
                 $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $sub_category->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                 $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
                 echo  '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" height="20" width="20">';
                //add other code here to display child details

            }   
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That code works and does show all of the categories but it doesn't display the thumbnail. I'll try to get it working.

Comment: oKay I am updating answer again for get thumbnail image. Thanks

Comment: Where's this code to must be put in? function.php of theme? Or?